# add dmesg logs to bugreport android

Tags: android, logging, android-source, dmesg

I am working in Android kernel, for some reason I need to add dmesg logs into bugreport  so if I use

> adb bugreport

I can get dmesg as well as other file inside bugreport.(suppose that I saved last dmesg in a persisted place)